# Prevent a request being processed with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

How to implement a 30 seconds 'cooldown', so I can prevent a controller action to be triggered?

I'm calling a .save method inside an action (not using ActiveStorage) and I want to prevent an accidental dupplication of requests (as I've seen happening before during my project).

Comment: use `rack-attack` and throttle it to 2req/min

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use cache to prevent accidental duplication of requests

```rb
def create
  key = # compute unique key base on request parameters,current_user,remote_ip ...
  unless Rails.cache.exist?(key)
   Rails.cache.write(key, true, expires_in: 30.seconds)
   # save model
   # response data
  else
   # response :not_modified or :nothing
  end
end
```

if you don't care about request data, just only want to limit number of requests per period of time, you can use rake middlewares [rack-attack](https://github.com/rack/rack-attack) or [rack-throttle](https://github.com/dryruby/rack-throttle)